# How to index path with python

Tags: python

How do I index a path with a counter (syntax it means) in Python? For example, I have this code:

```
while i<5:
    with open("xxx\\xxx\\test(i)","r+") as f:
        f.write("hello")
```

The output should be on 5 files: `test0`, `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import count
for i in count(0):
    if i >= 5:break
    with open(r"test {0}".format(str(i)), "w") as file:
        file.write("Hello World")
```

Comment: thnx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Use `.format()` to add the index to your filename. Also remember to include the initialization and incrementation of `i`, and open the file with write access.

```
i = 0
while i<5:
    with open("xxx\\xxx\\test({})".format(i), "w+") as f:
        f.write("hello")
    i += 1
```

Comment: thnx for your reply